# How to connect SQL Server with Metabase in local instance

Tags: java, sql-server, ssms, metabase

I am using windows 11 and I have installed SQL Server for learning purposes. While logging into the SQL Server I am using `Windows Authentication` which means I don't have any password for the username.

Now, I want to learn `Metabase`. So I have installed Metabase with a local instance by downloading the `Metabase Jar` from the Official Website of Metabase. I have successfully installed the  `Metabase` in the local instance and it is working fine.

Here comes the issue while connecting the SQL Server with Metabase I am facing issues and the connection is not established. It's saying  `Failed Try after 10.0 sec` only.

Can anyone who successfully connected SQL Server with Metabase tell me what details need to be provided in the below images? [image: Metabase Database connection] [image: Metabase Database connection] [image: Metabase Database connection]